# PDF reading in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pdf, formatting, pypdf

I have a pdf which has some table, FAQ, and content under few SubHeadings.

I am looking for a python code which will read the pdf and give me an array of strings with each subheading as an array element. - Is there any library to make python understand that this is a heading/subheading.

I tried using pyPdf2 - page.extractText() gives all the text in a page - But I was not able to split that into sections under each subheading.

Any experts to help me in this.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Do you have an example of your script, the expected output and the actual output?

Comment: Is there something distinctive about all of those subheadings? Do they all begin with a letter like a) First Subheading b) Second sub. Or maybe something distinctive at the end of each last paragraph just before the subheading?

| Side comment: [pyPdf2](https://pypi.org/project/PyPDF2/) doesn't look like is mantained anymore - you should use  [pypdf](https://pypi.org/project/pypdf/) instead

Comment: If you have access to the Word document that was used to generate the PDF, it might be easier to extract headers from the Word document with python

Comment: The sad thing is I dont have both the word document used and also distinctive side headings :( @Martin

Comment: I wish there could be a way to do it in Python.

Answer (score 0):

I am not capable of adding comments due to my lack of reputation. I just want to propose the use of a visual library perhaps cv2. I am not sure about the implementation or the feasibility, but I think that scanning the pdf and then analyzing it to tell the section title (bold) from the content (regular) might be a viable solution. Nonetheless as I have no clear idea about the code and the limitations, this idea can be more time consuming than the entire project.
Another possible idea, perhaps easier to implement is to use a free natural language model API to detect what is a title and what is the content of said section.

Answer (score 0):

**PyPDF2 is deprecated**, use pypdf. I'm the maintainer of both.

While there is no non-ML way to get the headings from arbitrary documents, several documents have an outline which is directly corresponding to the headings. You can read the outline with `pypdf`:

```
from pypdf import PdfReader
from pypdf.generic import NameObject

def print_outline(outline, nesting_level:int=0):
    for el in outline:
        if isinstance(el, list):
            print_outline(el, nesting_level+1)
        else:
            print("    " * nesting_level + el.title)

reader = PdfReader("GeoTopo.pdf")
print_outline(reader.outline)
```

A well-structured PDF like [GeoTopo.pdf](https://github.com/py-pdf/sample-files/blob/5b5ee6b0e9bf4b683490351b1e15e01d6553da7b/009-pdflatex-geotopo/GeoTopo.pdf) gives:

```
1 Topologische Grundbegriffe
    1.1 Topologische Räume
    1.2 Metrische Räume
    1.3 Stetigkeit
    1.4 Zusammenhang
    1.5 Kompaktheit
    1.6 Wege und Knoten
    Übungsaufgaben
2 Mannigfaltigkeiten und Simplizialkomplexe
    2.1 Topologische Mannigfaltigkeiten
    2.2 Differenzierbare Mannigfaltigkeiten
    2.3 Simplizialkomplex
    Übungsaufgaben
3 Fundamentalgruppe und Überlagerungen
    3.1 Homotopie von Wegen
    3.2 Fundamentalgruppe
    3.3 Überlagerungen
    3.4 Gruppenoperationen
4 Euklidische und nichteuklidische Geometrie
    4.1 Axiome für die euklidische Ebene
    4.2 Weitere Eigenschaften einer euklidischen Ebene
        4.2.1 Flächeninhalt
    4.3 Hyperbolische Geometrie
    Übungsaufgaben
5 Krümmung
    5.1 Krümmung von Kurven
    5.2 Tangentialebene
    5.3 Gauß-Krümmung
    5.4 Erste und zweite Fundamentalform
Lösungen der Übungsaufgaben
Bildquellen
Abkürzungsverzeichnis
Ergänzende Definitionen und Sätze
Symbolverzeichnis
Stichwortverzeichnis
```